# Storing data for an app in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am new to iphone development. Trying to develop an app. The data is around 2000 entries with around 150 characters. How is the data stored normally ? in plist ? xml ? cdv ? Which format will be fast for parsing ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a very simple structure, I recommend a PLIST. It is easy to use with NSMutableArray objects. For example, you read EntriesList.plist into myArray like that:

```
NSString path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EntriesList" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray* myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile];
```

But if you have a more complex structure, with a few tables / relations, then you better go with Core Data. It can use a sqlite database file under the hood, and easily handle data fetch requests in your code.

Answer (score 0):

2000 entries is not that big that it would give you much problem, but using JSON or PLIST will be faster than common XML, if you have complex structure you can use sqlite as well.